# Most secure server to server connection

Tags: python, ssl, network-programming, network-security

I need to build a Python application that receives highly secure data, decrypts it, and processes & stores in a database. My server may be anywhere in the world so direct connection is not feasible. What is the safest/smartest way to securely transmit data from one server to another (think government/bank-level security). I know this is quite vague but part of the reason for that is to not limit the scope of answers received.

Basically, if you were building an app between two banks (this has nothing to do with banks but just for reference), how would you securely transmit the data?

Sorry, I should also add SFTP probably will not cut it since this python app must fire when it is pinged from the other server with a secure data transmission.

Comment: Have you considered using a VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the safest/smartest way to securely transmit data from one server to another (think government/bank-level security)

It depends on your threat model, but intrasite VPN is sometimes used to tunnel traffic like this.

If you want to move up in the protocol stack, then mutual authentication with the client pinning the server's public key would be a good option.

In contrast, I used to perform security architecture work for a US investment bank. They did not use anything - they felt the leased line between data centers provided enough security.

Comment: JWW - thanks so much for this. I have a few more questions I'd like to take offline. Can I contact you somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Transmission and encryption need not happen together. You can get away with just about any delivery method, if you encrypt PROPERLY!

Encrypting properly means using a large, randomly generated keys, using HMACs (INSIDE! the encryption) and checking for replay attacks. There may also be a denial of service attack, timing attacks and so forth; though these may also apply to any encrypted connection. Check for data coming in out of order, late, more than once. There is also the possibility (again, depending on the situation) that your "packets" will leak data (e.g. transaction volumes, etc).

DO NOT, UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES, MAKE YOUR OWN ENCRYPTION SCHEME.

I think that public key encryption would be worthwhile; that way if someone collects copies of the encrypted data, then attacks the sending server, they will not have the keys needed to decrypt the data.

There may be standards for your industry (e.g. banking industry), to which you need to conform.

There are VERY SERIOUS PITFALLS if you do not implement this sort of thing correctly. If you are running a bank, get a security professional.

Comment: Thanks for this! If I am the once receiving and not sending, I cannot control the other end's encryption manner. We would probably need to agree upon this. One thing you didn't mention is how your python app would ingest the data? Through a SSL socket? Have the sending side POST it? Dump a file and read that? If this app will fire millions of times, which is the best method?

Comment: If you cannot control the other end, this conversation is moot; they could email it to a newspaper. If you are working with millions of "packets" (though you did not say over what time period), then I would personally use https, with a client certificate. If you don't trust the sender to write quality security software, get them to encrypt and sign it e.g. with DSA; that way you can refuse it if security protocols aren't followed. Keep your private key under lock & key. Openssl is easy enough to get and use.

Comment: The millions of packets would be daily; steady small requests on my server with < 5k of data. I would simply need to ensure what was sent was not hijacked during transmission, and I think your idea of the cert works best. However, transactions would not be via a webform; yet pulling from the clients db and sending me pings.

Answer (score 0):

There are several details to be considered, and I guess the question is not detailed enough to provide a single straight answer. But yes, I agree, the VPN option is definitely a safe way to do it, provided you can set up a VPN.

If not, the SFTP protocol (not FTPS) would be the next best choice, as it is PCI-DSS compliant (secure enough for banking) and HIPAA compliant (secure enough to transfer hospital records) and - unlike FTPS - the SFTP protocol is a subsystem of SSH and it only requires a single open TCP port on the server side (22).